# Add "new" tag for existing products

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, tags

Is there a way to add "new" tag for products, for products that have less than 14 days? I searched all over the internet, but I didn't find a solution. Please help me to do that with php, I will really appreciate. Thanks in advance! I have this code, but it doesn't work

```
function add_tags() {
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ): while ( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();

    global $product;

    wp_set_object_terms($product, array('nou'), 'product_tag');

endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();
```

}

Comment: Do you want to add a literal tag (tag taxonomy), or a small flash icon that says new over a product?, like you have if you have a product that has a sale price?

Comment: Hello, I made a heading and that heading looks like a badge (new badge). I used dynamic visibility to display that heading for products that have "new" tag and now I want to add that "new" tag for products that have less than 14 days.

Comment: If you do want an actual object_term as you've got in the code you probably want a daily scheduled job that searches for all products and checks if their [get_post_datetime](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_datetime/) is in the last 14 days or not and updates the nou tag. (Assuming that's the date you want to use - I don't know how WooCommerce products are set up.)